# Dynamic method calling for an arel operation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, arel

I have a piece of code involving an arel operation and want to optimize it .

```
case group_type
        when "week"
            gmv = OrderItem.joins(:order).where(order: {order_date: from_date..to_date }).group_by_week("order.order_date").sum("sub_total")
        when "month"
             gmv = OrderItem.joins(:order).where(order: {order_date: from_date..to_date }).group_by_month("order.order_date").sum("sub_total")
        when "day"
             gmv = OrderItem.joins(:order).where(order: {order_date: from_date..to_date }).group_by_day("order.order_date").sum("sub_total")
        end
```

I want a way by which i can write this in one line and just substitute "group_by_#{group_type}"

I can use eval. But using eval is not a good practice.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [public_send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-public_send).
So your code would be:

```
OrderItem.joins(:order).where(order: {order_date: from_date..to_date }).public_send("group_by_#{group_type}", "order.order_date").sum("sub_total")
```